# Creating an image with the 'jpeg' package of R does not yield the expected RGB values

Tags: r, image, jpeg, rgb

I have a 3d matrix in R with these values:

```
mypixels=c(rep(1,8),rep(0,40))
mymatrix=array(mypixels,dim=c(4,4,3))
structure(mymatrix)
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    0
[2,]    1    1    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0
[4,]    1    1    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0
```

Applying this order:

```
writeJPEG(mymatrix,"mypicture.jpg",quality = 1)
```

would be expected to produce half of the picture in red and the other half in black. However, the picture appears formed by four different columns displaying a left-to-right gradient from red to black. In fact, reading that picture shows:

```
mymatrix2=readJPEG("mypicture.jpg")
structure(mymatrix2)
, , 1

          [,1] [,2]      [,3] [,4]
[1,] 0.9960784  0.8 0.1490196    0
[2,] 0.9960784  0.8 0.1490196    0
[3,] 0.9960784  0.8 0.1490196    0
[4,] 0.9960784  0.8 0.1490196    0

, , 2

            [,1]       [,2] [,3]       [,4]
[1,] 0.007843137 0.08627451    0 0.01568627
[2,] 0.007843137 0.08627451    0 0.01568627
[3,] 0.007843137 0.08627451    0 0.01568627
[4,] 0.007843137 0.08627451    0 0.01568627

, , 3

     [,1]       [,2] [,3]       [,4]
[1,]    0 0.08235294    0 0.01568627
[2,]    0 0.08235294    0 0.01568627
[3,]    0 0.08235294    0 0.01568627
[4,]    0 0.08235294    0 0.01568627
```

Changing the quality to 0.5 produces a similar result (albeit with the values slightly different). So, how can I get a 100% quality, that is, without changes in the color values when writing the image?

Comment: When I run your code, exactly as you have it. I get square that is half red and half black, as expected.

Comment: You may consider updating your JPEG r-package.

Comment: As an additional note (sorry, missed the 5-minute cutoff), my `mydata2` structure looks just like yours too!

Comment: I am using the 0.1-8 version of this package, which seems to be the latest (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jpeg/index.html).

Comment: Have you tried reading in a known image and then writing it, to see if it changes between input and output?

Comment: Yes. In fact the problem in more complex images has led me to check it out in these simple conditions.

Comment: Hmm. That's really interesting. Is there ANY other code or packages running?

Comment: Just the default packages that come with the R and Rstudio installation.